# LDAP Acount Manager (LAM) can not use SSH public key module / OpenLDAP CentOS 6.4 SSL setup

Tags: ssh, openldap

I set up openLDAP server + client on a virtual machine running CentOS 6.4.

I config openLDAP with SSL and I can create user in LDAP Account Manager - [LAM](https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/).
Then I try to add the SSH public key module for user.

When I try to create a new user LAM returned:

```
Was unable to create DN: cn=test,ou=People,dc=local,dc=host.
Invalid syntax
```

Then I checked with Schema test then it shows up that SSH public key did not work with my LDAP server:

```
SSH public key XXX The object class ldapPublicKey is not supported by your LDAP server.
```

I know that **openssh-lpk** has integrated default in CentOS.
I installed openssh-ldap and tried to include openssh-lpk-openldap.schema path in /etc/openldap/slapd.conf:

```
include /usr/share/doc/openssh-ldap-5.3p1/openssh-lpk-openldap.schema
```

But it did work.

So what should I do next?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to remove the config file generated by slaptest in /etc/openldap/slapd.d
and then rerun the slaptest command again to generate the template with openssh-lpk schema. It worked.